# SQLAlchemy Aliase not instantiating constructor value

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, sqlalchemy-migrate

Recently we have migrated to newer latest version of SQLAlchemy. Below code was working without any issue in old version.

My class:

```
from redshift.classpath import HomePod

class User(HomePod):
__tablename__ = 'user'

customeraccountid = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
tenantid = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
userid = Column(String(128), primary_key=True)
acceptsmarketing = Column(Boolean)
createby = Column(String(128))
createdate = Column(TIMESTAMP)


__table_args__ = {}

def __init__(self, schema=HomePod): 
      self.__table__.schema = schema
```

I was using below code:

```
User_1 = aliased(User(schema='Myschemaname'))
```

But now, the schema name which I am passing not getting assigned to the class. I have tried below code as well. But no luck.

```
User_1 = aliased(User)
User_1.schema = 'myschemaname'
```

Someone please suggest what to do in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: I get an error if I pass a model instance (as opposed to a class) to `aliased`.